# how to pipe logfiles to python in nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, logging, pipe

How to pipe the nginx log output to a python script without saving it first in a logfile.
Currently I use apache and there I pipe it like this:

```
CustomLog "|/path/to/script.py"
```

In nginx the configuration for logfiles looks like the code below, now I need to pipe it to the python script

```
# Nginx access file:
$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/access.log
$InputFileTag nginx-access:
$InputFileStateFile stat-nginx-access
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
$InputRunFileMonitor

#Nginx Error file: 
$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/error.log
$InputFileTag nginx-error:
$InputFileStateFile stat-nginx-error
$InputFileSeverity error
$InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to nginx IRC channel I found a suitable solution, wich I'd like to share for the next person having the same issue.

```
http {
  #(...)


  map $remote_addr $anon_remote_addr {
    "~^(?<ip_a>\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\.\d+" "$ip_a";
  }
  log_format combined_anon '$anon_remote_addr.0.0 - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
  # Set it globally
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined_anon;


  #(...)
}
```

Snippet from: https://gist.github.com/fluential/e2b4ceea628ead5162f0

Comment: To be clear, this is a solution for anonymizing log files, _not piping the logs to an external program_ (which is what the question was about).